# Simplifying a query in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

(I'm not sure how to make the title more clear - feel free to edit it)

I have two tables with *wines* and *wineries*. Every wine has one winery assigned to it.
If I want to produce a list of all wines with the corresponding winery, I can do this:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Wine')->findAll();
```

and

```
{% for entity in entities %}
  {{ entity.winery.name }} {{ entity.name }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with this solution is that there is an extra query made for every winery which I want to prevent.

I tried the technique used in the [symfony2 manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-to-related-records) but I was unable to get it to work (does it work just for a single result?).

Normally with SQL, I would simply do a `LEFT JOIN` but I just can't figure out how to accomplish that in Doctrine2.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('w', 'wnr');
$qb->leftJoin('w.winery', 'wnr');
$qb->orderBy('w.name', 'ASC');

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

???

I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: SQL, DQL, own method. It's all listed in the manual page you linked.

Comment: @hakre: But how can I access it later? If I do left join like that I am unable to access the joined properties.

Comment: It depends what you try to achieve. As you're using the ORM, you normally do not want to use SQL. So step a bit aside from SQL and take a look if you can solve your issue with DQL. DQL will return the objects.

Comment: @hakre, I'm quite new to Symfony2 and ORM. I understand I receive objects. But as I've explained to Kuba, I don't yet quite understand how it is possible for me to get all the data I need in one query.

Comment: The query just returns multiple objects, that's it basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you select Winery in your DQL query?

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Wine')
    ->createQueryBuilder('w')
    ->select('w, wnr')
    ->leftJoin('w.winery', 'wnr');
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: I still have the same problem - how do I access it later? Because if I try to access property `wnr` on the wine, symfony complains there is no such method. That is quite understandable but does it mean I have to modify the Entity itself?

Comment: @Czechnology: Don't you use the getter method for that property?

Comment: Ok, I think I've finally got it and more or less understood it. My brain is still a bit stuck halfway between SQL and DQL. When I use the normal `winery` property in twig (that is the standard getter method) it works nicely with just one query. Thanks for your help!